# How do I add CSS to react-popout (window.open)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using Jake Ginnivan's react-popout package (wrapper for window.open) to open a popout window in my react code upon a button click. The problem is that the opened popout window contains none of the styling of the main app, and I'm not too sure how to add styling. As a result my content is super squished and I'm tried playing around with the components' containerId prop which adds and id to the popout in hopes of having it work with my existing CSS, but no luck. Any ideas?

https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/react-popout

Answer (score 1):

"Right now we do not support css in js. We use simple classes that you need to use in order for the popup to display correctly." - http://minutemailer.github.io/react-popup/

Looks like you just need to declare the same classes in your codebase to overwrite the defaults. For example:

```
.mm-popup__btn--danger {
    background-color: #c5545c;
    border-color: #c5545c;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This would set the the colors for the popup's danger button.

Comment: My bad, I was talking about react-**popout**, not react-**popup**. I edited the original post to reflect that.

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question, as this answer has already been upvoted for the original question :) I wouldn't want to confuse anyone